# Flutter Fingerprint only show the fingerprint without the grey dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using local auth for biometric in flutter for authentication I want to use display the fingerprint icon to unlock the phone without the dialog how to achieve this?

Comment: On iOS you cannot avoid the OS specific dialog.

Comment: Ok, what about android